# Getting unique count of each ticket along with No of days in each assignment queue in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, element

I am creating small POC which will tell me how many days each ticket remains with each different team. (L1, L2 are team names)

[image]

Comment: I have N number of excels, I have merged them in single excel and sorted already now trying to Get each unique ticket number along with a count of days it spends in each different team if it's completed or not completed in both conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have read your Excel files into a DataFrame and
*Age of ticket in days* column in it contains either empty strings
or a number (not *NaN*), just as on your picture.

Start from generating a temporary DataFrame:

```
wrk = df.groupby(['Ticket No', 'Assignment queue']).Status.count()\
    .unstack().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
wrk.columns.name = None
```

The result, for your data sample is:

```
           L1  L2
Ticket No        
INC001      1   3
INC002      3   1
INC003      4   0
INC004      1   3
```

And to get the result, run:

```
result = wrk.add_prefix('No of days in ').add_suffix(' Queue')\
    .join(df.groupby('Ticket No')['Age of ticket in days'].last()
    .rename('Total number of days for resolution'))\
    .reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
  Ticket No  No of days in L1 Queue  No of days in L2 Queue  Total number of days for resolution 
0    INC001                       1                       3                                    4  
1    INC002                       3                       1                                       
2    INC003                       4                       0                                    4  
3    INC004                       1                       3                                    4
```

## Edit

If *Age of ticket in days* column in the source DataFrame does contain
*NaN*s, a small correction is needed: Just add `.fillna('')` after `last()`.

## A remark concerning the source data (following your comment)

Note that each row states **only** the sequence of assignments for each
ticket, without actual dates when particular ticket has been assigned and
then passed to another team (or completed).

This is why:

- I assumed that each row is something like "report at the end of
  consecutive day".
- The way how *wrk* is computed is actually to **count** in how many rows
  the particular ticket was assigned to each team (assuming "1 row per
  day" rule).
- On the other hand, *Age of ticket* is given apparently without any
  defined connection to the above rule. It **should** be equal to the
  number of rows for particular ticket, but I don't know whether this
  rule is observed in each case (for each ticket).

For your sample data there was no such discrepancies, but in other
rows the may occur.

Or maybe your DataFrame should contain in each row:

- the "start date" - when this ticket was assigned to this team,
- the "end date" - when this ticket was either assigned to some
  other team or completed.

Then:

- rows with the same *start* and *end* date should not be counted,
- each row should "contribute" (to the team in question) the number
  of days resulting from the difference between *end* and *start* date.

In this case the last column would be not needed.

Comment: Hi Valdi, thanks a lot mate for your answer, Now code is executing perfectly and print(wrk) is working as expected but when I have tried with some changes in No of tickets in input then print(result) is giving some unexpected answer
Incident.:--------------------------------------------- No of days in L1 Queue--- No of days in L2 Queue --Total number of days for resolution
INC001 4 0 2
INC002 4 0 0
INC003 4 0 
INC004 1 3 
INC005 0 3 
INC006 0 3 
INC007 3 0 3
INC008 0 2 
INC009 2 0 5
INC010 1 0